# How to use http client in c# console app in .net 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, console-application, httpclient, .net-6.0

Net 6 console app. I am trying to call rest api as below.

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
      string baseAddress = "https://webservices.com/rest/?step=1&token=3gBBVtQ6evuHb0EQ0Zt";
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new
      MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      HttpResponseMessage response = await
      client.GetAsync(baseAddress).ConfigureAwait(false);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
           string txtBlock = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                      
      }
      else
      {
                      
      }
}
```

In program.cs i have added

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
.AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
```

when  hit client.GetAsync program get terminates without any exception. I added try and catch but still it wont catch exception so unable to find root cause

Comment: Your code explicitly ignores failures with `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)`. How would you know if the server returned an error message? You can replace all of the code with `var text=await client.GetStringAsync(url);` which will throw if the status code indicates failure. Instead of explictly creating HttpClient though, you should use the client you registered with `.AddHttpClient()`. Or *not* use `ServiceCollection` at all.

Comment: Hi, could you pls let me know if I misunderstood your requirement? so that we can continue to investigate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should working.
But be carefful, if you use

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
.AddHttpClient().BuildServiceProvider();
```

you should use

```
var client = serviceProvider.GetService<HttpClient>();
```

rathen than

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want? I created a .net 6 console application and follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient).

```
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text.Json;


using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/orgs/dotnet/repos");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.github.v3+json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", ".NET Foundation Repository Reporter");
    await using Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://api.github.com/orgs/dotnet/repos");
    var repositories = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Repository>>(stream);
    foreach (var repo in repositories)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {repo.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Homepage: {repo.Homepage}");
        Console.WriteLine($"GitHub: {repo.GitHubHomeUrl}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Description: {repo.Description}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Watchers: {repo.Watchers:#,0}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{repo.LastPush}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Complete");
}
```

[image]